# callback function in MessageBox Ext JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I need `validate` function to return `true` if user agreed with alert, but the program stops and doesn't react to yes or no buttons. Any ideas?
P.S. when I remove Ext.Msg.alert everything is working...

```
validate: function () {
    var isValid = this.callParent();
    if (isValid) {
        Ext.Msg.alert({
            title :'',
            msg : '.....',
            buttons : Ext.Msg.YESNO,
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION,

            fn : function(btn){
                if (btn == 'yes'){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. Messages are asynchronous in ExtJs.

`alert` will be called and execution will continue. Callback function will be called in a different queue of execution when user pressed a button.

You need to re-design your logic, so you don't depend on validate return value, but rather have couple functions - one will be called when validation succeeded and another when it failed.

Comment: i also tried this one, but it's the same....validate: function () {
        Ext.Msg.confirm("", "Are you sure?'", function (btn) {
            if (btn === 'yes') {
                .....superclass.validate.call(this);
            }
        }, this);
    }